# Scripted Restore Using xp_DirTree For Transient Logical BAK File Name SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I am trying to restore a DB from one server to another where the logical name of the .bak file changes daily with a new timestamp, I have so far found success in determining this name using the following SQL script provided by Jeff Moden here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1200360-391-1.aspx

```
            --===== Create a holding table for the file names
             CREATE TABLE #File
                    (
                    FileName    SYSNAME,
                    Depth       TINYINT,
                    IsFile      TINYINT
                    )
            ;
            --===== Capture the names in the desired directory
                 -- (Change "C:\Temp" to the directory of your choice)
             INSERT INTO #File
                    (FileName, Depth, IsFile)
             EXEC xp_DirTree '\\filepath\',1,1
            ;
            --===== Find the latest file using the "constant" characters
                 -- in the file name and the ISO style date.
             SELECT TOP 1 
                    FileName
               FROM #File
              WHERE IsFile = 1
                AND FileName LIKE '%.bak' ESCAPE '_'
              ORDER BY FileName DESC
            ;
            DROP TABLE #File
```

My question is now how do I use this as the basis of a scripted restore operation? any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found success by extending the above to cache the directory path and ordered bak files chronologically to determine which to use, then combined the restore operation, with move for logs.

```
--==CHECK IF DB EXISTS IF IT DOES DROP IT
USE [master]
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases where name='insert db name')
DROP DATABASE [insert db name]

--==START THE RESTORE PROCESS
DECLARE @FileName varchar(255), @PathToBackup varchar(255), @RestoreFilePath varchar(1000)
DECLARE @Files TABLE (subdirectory varchar(255), depth int, [file] int)
SET NOCOUNT ON

--==SET THE FILEPATH
SET @PathToBackup = '\\insert path to back up'

 --insert into memory table using dirtree at a single file level
 INSERT INTO @Files
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree @PathToBackup,1,1
     SELECT TOP 1 
        @FileName = [subdirectory]
     FROM 
        @Files
     WHERE
        -- get where it is a file
        [file] = 1
     AND 
     --==FIND THE LOGICAL NAME OF THE BAK FILE FROM THE CHRONILOGICALLY ORDERED LIST   
        subdirectory LIKE '%.bak'
     ORDER BY
        -- order descending so newest file will be first by naming convention
     subdirectory DESC

IF LEFT(REVERSE(@PathToBackup), 1) != '\'
BEGIN
    SET @PathToBackup = @PathToBackup + '\'
END
SET @RestoreFilePath = @PathToBackup + @FileName

--Grab the file path to restore from
SELECT @RestoreFilePath

--BEGIN THE RESTORE TO THE DESIGNATED SERVER
RESTORE DATABASE [insert name of database to restore] 
FROM DISK = @RestoreFilePath
WITH
FILE = 1,
--Create transactional log files on target
MOVE 'mdf_file_name' TO 'file_path\file.mdf',
MOVE 'log_file_name' TO 'file_path\file.ldf', REPLACE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that I have partly written and partly collected.
Features include:

1. Imports exactly one backup file that has any file name with .bak
   ending. If there are more files, then imports only one without any
   errors.
2. If no files exist, gives an error.
3. Kicks users out from the database.
4. Deletes the backup file

   ```
   DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(255), @FileName nvarchar(255), @PathToBackup nvarchar(255), @RestoreFilePath nvarchar(1000)
   DECLARE @Files TABLE (subdirectory nvarchar(255), depth int, [file] int)
   SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

   SET @PathToBackup = N'I:\Folder'

   -- insert into our memory table using dirtree and a single file level
   INSERT INTO @Files
   EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree @PathToBackup,1,1

   SELECT 
   @FileName = [subdirectory]
   FROM 
   @Files
   WHERE
   -- get where it is a file
   [file] = 1
   AND    
   subdirectory LIKE N'%.bak'
   ORDER BY
   -- order descending so newest file will be first by naming convention
   subdirectory DESC

   IF LEFT(REVERSE(@PathToBackup), 1) != N'\'
   BEGIN
       SET @PathToBackup = @PathToBackup + N'\'
   END

   SET @RestoreFilePath = @PathToBackup + @FileName
   SET @DBName = LEFT(@FileName, LEN(@FileName)-4)
   --  SELECT 'Replace AdventureWorks2016CTP3 in this script with @DBName'

   SELECT @RestoreFilePath
   BEGIN TRY
   -- You can try to check if this command works "already":
   --  ALTER DATABASE  [@DBName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
       ALTER DATABASE  [AdventureWorks2016CTP3] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

   -- You can try to check if this command works "already":
   --    RESTORE DATABASE [@DBName] 
       RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2016CTP3] 
       FROM DISK = @RestoreFilePath
       WITH FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
   -- You can try to check if this command works "already":
   --  ALTER DATABASE  [@DBName] SET MULTI_USER;
       ALTER DATABASE  [AdventureWorks2016CTP3] SET MULTI_USER;
       ; THROW
   END CATCH

   -- You can try to check if this command works "already":
   --  ALTER DATABASE  [@DBName] SET MULTI_USER;
       ALTER DATABASE  [AdventureWorks2016CTP3] SET MULTI_USER;

   -- This script is especially for the case where you replication from one location to another using backup and restore. 
   -- Typically you don't need transaction log backups as all changes will be wiped out on next transfer.
   -- You can try to check if this command works "already":
   --  ALTER DATABASE  [@DBName] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
       ALTER DATABASE  [AdventureWorks2016CTP3] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

   -- Delete file(s)
   -- NOTE: This works only if you give deletion permissions as defined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017
   -- EXAMPLE: exec xp_cmdshell 'del "I:\Directory\AdventureWorks2016CTP3___.bak"'
   -- exec xp_cmdshell 'del "' + '@PathToBackup + ''\'' + @FileName + ''"''
   DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'xp_cmdshell ''del "' + @PathToBackup + @FileName + '"''';
   -- SELECT @cmd
   EXEC (@cmd)
   ```